# zfs raidz1-0 corrupted data, all disks are online

Tags: zfs

My zfs pool "datas" is unavailable but all my disks are online.
Do you know how the problem can be fixed?

```
root@oxygen:~# zpool status
pool: datas
state: UNAVAIL
scan: none requested

config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    datas                                   UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
      raidz1-0                              UNAVAIL      0     0     0  corrupted data
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0LBVX  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0KYX9  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0LCC8  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0LBXZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: Is `zpool clear datas` improving the pool state ?

Comment: No... `sudo zpool clear datas` return `cannot clear errors for datas: invalid argument for this pool operation`

Comment: `zpool clear datas scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0LBVX
cannot clear errors for scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_W1F0LBVX: invalid argument for this pool operation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved, the new kernel "3.2.0-30-generic" and the new version of zfs-dkm 0.6.0.76 seems to be not compatible at this time.

So I've recompiled the module and boot on the old kernel.